# What are the ways to make layered block in css

Tags: html, css

I need to make the following page design

[image]

I came up with the following coordinates rotation idea, but it's not working for now: I tried to stack it in Y-axis but the first one overlayes others and I don't know how to make others two visible.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #b4e0e1;
}

.layer-container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -250px;
    perspective: 500px;
   transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.layer {
    width: 500px;
    height: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1;
}


/* dark blue layer */

.dark-blue-layer {
    background: #234688;
}


/* light blue layer */

.light-blue-layer {
    background: #2abfd5;
}

.white-layer {
    background: #fff;
}

.bottom-layer {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(-25deg) translateX(0px);
}

.mid-layer {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(-25deg) translateX(20px);
}

.top-layer {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(-25deg) translateX(40px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="layer-container stacked-top">
        <div class="layer bottom-layer dark-blue-layer"></div>
        <div class="layer mid-layer light-blue-layer"></div>
        <div class="layer top-layer white-layer"></div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can it be improved and is there another simplier way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused by your transform settings and what you are trying to achieve, but to get the look from the green image you can use `box-shadow` to simulate "background layers":

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #b4e0e1;
}

.layer-container {
    width: 260px;
    height: 140px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 20px auto;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 0 #234688, 10px 10px 0 0 #2abfd5;
}
```

```html
<div class="layer-container"></div>
```